# I need to prevent a python script from running twice

Tags: python

I need to prevent a python script from running more than once. So far I have:

```
import fcntl
def lockFile(lockfile):
    fp = open(lockfile, 'w')
    try:
        fcntl.flock(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
    except IOError:
        return False

    return True

if not lockFile("myfile.lock"):
    sys.exit(0)
```

Problem is the sys.exit() never gets called even if the file is there. Maybe this is a platform dependent way of doing things? I just need to write a lockfile, check for its existence and if it's not there or stale, create a new one. Ideas?

Comment: Is there an error message you get when you remove the try-except clauses and just call the lock?

Comment: Nope, no errors. Lock file gets written if it's not there.

Comment: and if it is there, what do you want to do?

Comment: If it's there I don't want the script to run.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a file will create a new file if none exist; you could instead try to read the file first: if there is none, an error is raised and a file a file written; if there is a file, the program exits.

```
try:
    with open('lockfile.txt', 'r') as f:
        lock = f.readline().strip().split()
        if lock[0] == 'locked':
            print('exiting')
            sys.exit(0)

except FileNotFoundError:
    with open('lockfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('locked')

    print('file written')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pass
```

If you need something more sophisticated, you could look up the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you file exists by using `os.path.exists` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)). If it does, then you can use the `sys.exit` you mentioned before. If you need something more than `sys.exit`, try the `atexit` module [@Reblochon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50421717/5645103) suggested. The script will then assume the file is ready to lock and the method will report its success back to the user via a boolean.

```
import os
import sys

import fcntl

FILE_NAME = 'myfile.lock'

def lockFile(lockfile):
    fp = open(lockfile, 'w') # create a new one
    try:
        fcntl.flock(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        success = True # the file has been locked
    except IOError:
        success = False # an error occurred
    fp.close() # make sure to close your file
    return success

if os.path.exists(FILE_NAME): # exit the script if it exists
    sys.exit(0)

print('success', lockFile(FILE_NAME))
```